# "Cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object" extracting mac addresses with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

HI I'm a beginner in python and i'm trying to create a code that can change the MAC address. The process of changing the MAC address works and now i'm trying to use ReGex to filter only the MAC IN A FUNCTION and have the following output instead of having all the 'Ifconfig' informations:
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

I got two files, the main one and the functions file;

in the **main** i got:

```
filterMAC(Options.inter)
#where Options.inter contains the interface information using the subprocess module
```

in the **functions** file i got:

```
def filterMAC(inter):
    eth0_info = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", inter ])
    infoMAC = re.findall("\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", eth0_info)
    print(infoMAC)
```

AND THE **ERROR** IS:

```
File "/home/eli/Desktop/MACPROJECT/Program.py", line 14, in <module>
    filterMAC(Options.inter)
  File "/home/eli/Desktop/MACPROJECT/FUNCTIONS.py", line 31, in filterMAC
    infoMAC = re.findall("\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", eth0_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT USE ALL CAPS IN YOUR TITLE

Comment: ...also, think about searching for the error ("cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object") before asking a new question; it's been asked about, and answered, before. When you're matching against a bytestring, you want to compile your regex _as_ a bytestring (`br'...'` -- the `b` means it's 8-bit characters, not wide/unicode characters)

Comment: (Also, you should only tag "kali-linux" if the problem _only_ happens on Kali; only tag `linux` if it only happens on Linux; only tag visual-studio-code if you can't make the problem happen without using VS Code; etc).